# Stripping HTML from text using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is the text I am trying to clean up:

```
Infographic: What is BPA? Why does it get such a bad rap? Discover more about it in our       
infographic - Why BPA will not kill you. (See a larger version here: <a   
rel="nofollow">https://www.containerandpackaging.com/sam/blog/infographics/infographic_ 
WhyBPAWontKillYou.jpg</a> )<br/><br/><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" 
href="http://www.facebook.com/containerandpackaging/photos/a.268688407811.176198.266913
322811/10152627992307812/?type=1&relevant_count=1" id="" title="" style=""><img   
class="img" src="http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-  
9/s130x130/10600407_10152627992307812_1312617274906388391_n.jpg?    
oh=505a27309629d804d894521dc035bce2&oe=5459BBC9&__gda__=1413295158_68fb27fae5cc75b8264a
8f5912613fc5" alt=""/></a><br/>
```

Here is my original javascript code: 
var content = item.description.replace(/]*>/g,"").replace(/\/g, "");
content = stripHtml(content);

The output looks something like this:

Infographic: What is BPA? Why does it get such a bad rap? Discover more about it in our infographic - Why BPA will not kill you. (See a larger version here: ht...

Is there a way to do this in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Angular's `$sanitize` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS uses JavaScript as a base, and it doesn't have anything special to strip HTML, so you should keep using your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular includes jQuery this is easy.  Put the HTML in a container you can target like and use the jQuery method .text(). Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new").val($("#original").text());
})
</head>
<body>
<div id="original">
  Infographic: What is BPA? Why does it get such a bad rap? Discover more about it in our       
infographic - Why BPA will not kill you. (See a larger version here: <a   
rel="nofollow">https://www.containerandpackaging.com/sam/blog/infographics/infographic_ 
WhyBPAWontKillYou.jpg</a> )<br/><br/><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" 
href="http://www.facebook.com/containerandpackaging/photos/a.268688407811.176198.266913
322811/10152627992307812/?type=1&relevant_count=1" id="" title="" style=""><img   
class="img" src="http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-  
9/s130x130/10600407_10152627992307812_1312617274906388391_n.jpg?    
oh=505a27309629d804d894521dc035bce2&oe=5459BBC9&__gda__=1413295158_68fb27fae5cc75b8264a
8f5912613fc5" alt=""/></a><br/>
  </div>
  <textarea id="new" cols="40" rows="10">
  </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/xovijoko/1/edit?html,js,output